# How can I get Serana to pick up items?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

Ok, so most followers in this game are able to hold a limited amount of items when you trade with them, but can hold an infinite number of items with a glitch (I'm not really sure if it is a glitch or if it was intentional).  You have to ask them to do something and then tell them to pick up an item or take all from a chest/container.  However, I can't get Serana to do it because she doesn't have the "I need you to do something." dialogue option.  Is there a way to get her to pick up items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at her feet and hold down the select button for a few seconds, then let go, it will give you the odd, x-shaped cursor that you get when you ask followers to do something.  You can then move to the item/container and press the select button again.  You can then exit the action the same way you would with the infinite inv. glitch.  This works with all followers that I have encountered.  I have only done this with the PS3 version (although I didn't have Dawngaurd on there, so I couldn't actually do it with Serana... but it worked with every other follower I actually tried) and PS4 Skyrim Special Edition.

Answer (score 1):

So I had this issue too but if I just hold A it auto gets me to tell her what to do (I'm playing on the Switch).
Hope this helps anyone having this issue today.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I said in my answer, below. I have noticed that the anniversary update changed things to allow you to just hold the button without looking at the feet, but you used to *have* to look at the feet to get this to work.